# what is the sink in streamcontroller in flutter

Tags: flutter

in that code `ctrl` streamController with `sink` and without `sink` both print data 
i don't understand why we need `sink`?

```dart
final StreamController ctrl = StreamController();
  final StreamSubscription subscription = ctrl.stream.listen((data) => print('$data'));

  ctrl.sink.add('Hello Stream');
  ctrl.add('Hello Stream');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sink adds your "Hello Stream" in a StreamSinkWrapper and then runs ctrl.add()

The wrapper may do things you may not be aware of now or in the future with an update. eg it has a close method, so you may get memory leaks if you don't use sink.

So although you can use a streamController without a sink, doesn't mean you should.